# Vertices, Edges, and Faces Buttons in Edit Mode Disappeared

Tags: interface, edit-mode

[image]

I was following a rigging tutorial on youtube, lots of shortcuts, and I think I might've accidentally pressed something?
I tried restarting, updated from 3.0 to 3.2, still no buttons. When I open another project, they're there.

Comment: You've selected your armature, press Ctrl Tab to switch back to Object mode and this time select the Object

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that. It is 5 in the morning for me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've selected your armature after your object, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch back to *Object* mode and this time select the object only